# Electro-mechanical relay durability curve

Tags: relay, inductive, snubber

For general-purpose electro-mechanical relays, it is often mentioned in datasheets the number of cycles under various categories of load (AC1, AC15, DC1, DC13 etc.). For example, the following image:

[image]

My main interest is DC-1 and DC-13 curves, as I want to use contacts of my relay to drive another electromecanical relay. I know that DC-13 loads are typical relay coils without any protection (freewheeling diode or snubber RC) and DC1 is a non or light inductive load.

My question is: if I add protection means (freewheeling diode or RC snubber) to DC-13 load, can I use the DC-1 curve instead? My intuition makes me say yes because the reactions of an inductive load (inductive kickback, high voltage and current surge) are suppressed by the protection. However, I need more concrete proof than just intuition.

Can anyone who has came across the same challenge spare me some time, please
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you just test a sample or two. I would expect it to be between the two.

Comment: In addition to what @SpehroPefhany says, it's going to depend on the design of the snubber, and "better" snubbers in that regard may well consume more current.  I think my first action would be to try to talk to an apps engineer at the relay company.