# How can I make a reliable tick tock sound electro-mechanically?

Tags: arduino, sound

I'm hoping to help someone make a [metronome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metronome)-like device,  but it'll tick like a clock once per second, all of the time. I was wondering how to produce that sound in a reliable way. There are 32 millionish seconds in a year, and I hope our thingie will last a bit longer.

1. The obvious way is to use a large relay, and pulse it at ½ Hz. That said, I read [Electro-mechanical relay durability curve](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/457020/56469) and it caused me to fear that a relay probably wouldn't last, especially not a big one that makes a decent ticking sound.
2. The next thought was a speaker cone, but they don't really make any noise unless actually vibrating making a 'ticking noise' from an audio recording.
3. Solenoid hitting something? Probably less reliable than the relay option.

There will be an Arduino inside the thingie. So, please?

Surprised no one hass spotted my deliberate mistake :-) A large relay clicking upon closing and opening, one tic per second, is powered at ½ Hz not 1 Hz.

Comment: clock movement .

Comment: @jsotola Brilliant idea, but I can imagine it being difficult to buy an sufficiently loud one. We have clocks in the house, and all are different loudness's. Most are silent.  And they don't advertise movements on the basis of how quiet or loud they are...

Comment: your post says nothing about the desired sound level

Comment: Are you saying that you don't want a speaker to be the mechanical part? It's dead easy to make a clocked bistable multivibrator circuit and connect it straight to a small speaker. It sounds pretty much like a tick. I know because I made one years ago with a simple circuit, a tin can and and a miniature speaker.

Comment: @jsotola It's implied by "metronome" which link you of course followed...

Comment: If you want it to last "forever" forget about doing it mechanically.  Use a micro to play a "click" sound through a speaker.

Comment: >> A large relay clicking upon closing and opening, one tic per second, is powered at ½ Hz not 1 Hz.   That's 2 hertz.  One full cycle every 2 seconds

Comment: Hang on, you're on about the tick-tock sound we all know (well, not BMW drivers) from using the indicators in our cars. It is made just by sending a 1Hz square wave to a speaker. The same signal also goes to the bulbs outside the car and the little light in the dashboard, not accounting for all the detail I missed out.

Answer (score 13):

If you want something simple, just send a pulse to a speaker. My ancient DIY Geiger counter basically did this. You won't have much control over the sound, but it may be sufficient for your needs.

You probably should put a big cap in series so you don't send any DC to the speaker.

Comment: This is a wonderful idea if one is not fussy about sound-of-a-tick. It may be possible to augment the speaker resonance by confining it to a small enclosure. You might be able to discriminate between "tick" and "tock" by changing pulse-width, allowing a longer pulse for "tock".

Comment: A speaker could tolerate some DC. But the capacitor will massively reduce the current draw, while having little impact on the sound. That might bring it within the current capability of the arduino (though transients would still exceed the datasheet.) The circuit needs to be able to sink as well as source in order to discharge the capacitor. I'd experiment with piezo elements as well as these won't draw too much current and may be loud enough.

Comment: @glen_geek If you pulse a speaker manually at 1hz by connecting / disconnecting it to the terminals of a battery, the tick and tock usually sound slightly different anyway.

Comment: @LevelRiverSt Yes, attack edge differs from release edge - because the attack edge dampens the speaker's resonance with a very low source impedance of the battery, while the release edge leaves the speaker's resonance un-damped. Attack would likely give you a "tick" while release gives you a "tock". But a constant-impedance source (like a function generator) damps the attacking edge similarly to the release edge, so "tick", "tick", "tick"....

Comment: @glen_geek that may well be the reason. But asymmetry can be achieved in other ways. If you don't care about current draw, rig a speaker up like a relay coil with an NPN transistor: Emitter to ground, collector to +V via coil. The impedance of transistor and flyback diode (if you really need one with a speaker, I've seen plenty of speakers wired like this without) will surely be different.  If you do care about current draw, use a parallel diode&resistor in series with the capacitor. I like your answer because it would DEFINITELY work. But I'd try something simple like Mattman's answer first.

Answer (score 13):

> The obvious way is to use a large relay, and pulse it at 1 Hz. That said, I read Electro-mechanical relay durability curve and it caused me to fear that a relay probably wouldn't last. Especially a big one to make a decent ticking.

The biggest factor in relay lifetime is actually contacts switching with load, and supply leads bending. If you ignore that, and only want the ticking, the relay has really few movable parts, and doesn't wear out easily.

From the curve you posted, that device is rated for *at least* ten million operations under no load. That's 2777 hours of ticking at 1Hz. My bet is that the device operating under no load would survive for at least twice that.

Comment: Ten million seconds is still only about four months. But a few -- maybe five -- identical relays driven by a decade counter would extend the life to well over the required year.

Comment: In reality I would guess it lasts far longer with no load...

Comment: A month of buzzing a couple dozen relays at 15 Hz would probably give a good idea.

Comment: @MattS Another consideration is that the electrical parameters of the relay are completely irrelevant here, so even if there's a failure resulting in the relay making unreliable contact, as long as it still makes a noise it still works for this purpose.

Comment: How long would it take, I wonder, for the moving contact to physically bash off enough metal atoms to make a difference? I almost want to build that 15 Hz test device.

Comment: @MattS Would take nearly forever. On a lathe, holding maroon Scotchbrite to a piece aluminum on a lathe at 500 surface feet per minute for a couple of minutes only takes off a couple tent thousands of an inch which is surely removing far more than when relay contacts bounce off each other. Metal fatigue would probably  be a problem before loss of material

Comment: Which reminds me...the bimetallic blinker mechanism on a car. Some of those are really loud.

Comment: I'd hope the steel in the relay was operating entirely within its fatigue limit (and would never fatigue). I've never actually opened up a relay's potting to see how physically large the contacts are though.

Comment: @MattS I would too but something has got to give eventually and I don't know what that would be.

Comment: 217F suggests that the load stress isn't that huge. You're probably looking at something slightly less than a 5x multiplier, which your other math still says is an MTBF < 2 years. My rough guess at form factors and quality gave an answer in the same ballpark as yours otherwise, so this is probably right.

Answer (score 10):

- WWV transmits a "ticking" sound as five cycles of a 1000 Hz sine wave.
- WWVH transmits a similar "ticking" sound as six cycles of a 1200 Hz sine wave.

When reproduced linearly into a loudspeaker, these bursts might satisfy. When alternated, they may sound like "tick", "tock".

Be aware that average should be zero. That is, the positive peak of the sine wave should extend above zero just as far as its negative peak extends below zero.
A web search reveals [recordings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eMCI9I6xn6A) of these one-second ticks from WWV, WWVH radio stations.

---

Edit: OP considers square wave rather than sinusoidal waveform:
Inverting buffers might be used to drive a loudspeaker with 1kHz square wave. Average of zero is met by balanced drivers having opposing polarity. Tri-state input is used to idle between "ticks" with no power delivered to loudspeaker:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJFKm7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: waveform from tristate inverter]

Comment: So I could output a bit of square wave, RC filter it to a sinusoid and then perhaps through a simple 2 transistor class B amp?

Comment: Just done it in Audacity. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulUszak Yes, was thinking of Audacity. See recent edit regarding square-wave driver.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions.  But why drive +-?  Can we not just drive the cone one way from rest, even if the sound might be lesser? That would reduce the component count.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use a relay as a clicker, you should test it, since the way you plan to use it is not within any specifications usually. Sometimes, relay manufacturers specify the *mechanical life* of the relay as a separate line in the specs, but it's not very common.

The "relay life" specification is usually called "contact life" and only applies to contact resistance staying below the maximum limiting value given in the datasheet. It does *not* mean that the relay will mechanically fall apart anytime soon!

Other answers suggest that the mechanical life may be, say, 2x the contact life at rated load. My experience is that without the contacts loaded, most relays will last an extremely long time - orders of magnitude longer than the contact life. As an anecdote, I have tested NEC's now-obsolete MR62 series relays, rated IIRC for a million contact actuations, and got tired of the clicking after they were past a billion cycles. They sounded just as good, and there was nothing obvious that would indicate that they were ready to fall apart.

And finally, the sound a relay makes depends on size and specific mechanical design. Some relays sound fairly similar upon both opening and closing, some have a distinctive *tick* and *tock* sounds. For small relays - say 2cm^3 or less - the sound is quite similar on either opening or closing, so indeed 0.5Hz square wave drive will give proper results.

For maximum coil life, the drive current waveform should have a peak value high enough to produce a satisfying click, and a hold value that's a couple times lower than the peak, to minimize the coil dissipation. A simple way to achieve that is to power the coil through a parallel R-C circuit.

"Clicker" applications that demand long relay life should drive the coil with a voltage source of a roughly fixed ON and OFF impedance, i.e. with an actual square wave waveform, so that the coil never "sees" an open circuit. This minimizes the voltage stress on the coil. In practice, this means a push-pull driver stage, e.g. one half of an H-bridge.

Comment: So in this situation, you suggest that the coil is the weakest link and needs careful treatment?

Comment: @PaulUszak When long lifetime is a concern, I find it best to treat the coils gently. They do develop a wire break sometimes - I've never had one fail before a billion cycles though. (I do these tests when working on my relay computer project)

Comment: And is there a blatant link (take the opportunity - this is HNQ)  to your project :-)

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica how long did it take you to cycle a relay a billion times? 100 times a second for 4 months?

Comment: A flyback diode, like *everyone* uses, seems easier than a push-pull driver. Unless you need the relay to switch off quickly (milliseconds faster) do you really need a push-pull driver?

Comment: @user253751: A simple flyback diode will cause a relay to be somewhat sluggish when switching off.  Using more sophisticated switching circuits may result in cleaner switching behavior.

Comment: @PaulUszak No links because it was an internal test for an ongoing long-term relay computer project that will take another year or two. I'm pushing hard to finish the hardware, as there are some external deadlines I want to meet.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can find one of the older mechanical Accessible Pedestrian Signal generators, the ones that make a slow/fast ticking sound at pedestrian traffic lights to help the blind. They are loud and last a long time. No idea if they are/were an international thing, though.

Or a ratchet or a ratcheting socket wrench with a stepper motor attached. Or an older, mechanical car indicator light, um, driver.

Or, if it doesn't have to be mechanical, just play a sample in a loop over a speaker.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a $2 voice recorder IC such as [ISD2360](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nuvoton-technology-corporation/ISD2360SYI/3507392), and record whatever sounds you like for the tick-tock.

There are others that should work as well. Or you could just copy a digital sound recording into an EPROM and play it back.

There are some complex sound generator and synthesizer chips like [SN76489](https://www.instructables.com/SN76489-Synthesizer/), [SN76489](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_Instruments_SN76489), and [SN76495](https://www.radiomuseum.org/tubes/tube_sn76495.html), although they may be hard to find. They were used in arcade games for sounds like sirens and machine guns. The [UM3561](https://www.instructables.com/Siren-Generation-using-IC-UM3561/) was specifically for those.

Here are some projects:
https://www.homemade-circuits.com/make-single-chip-programmable/

This might help:
https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/30882/mini-voice-recorder-for-arduino

I found one on AliExpress for 50 cents. I'll leave it up to you if you want to go that ultra-cheap route.

Comment: +1 Generate (simple) sound on a system with a μC? Total no-brainer. Furthermore this approach provides for future extensibility via nothing but a firmware update.